# Running python script with php

Tags: python, php

Im trying to run a python script with php, but for some reason, the python script doesnt open!c

My php code:

```
 <?php
           echo $valor_estado = file_get_contents("../files/porta/valor.txt");
           if ($valor_estado == "Aberta"){
            
            $path = escapeshellcmd("localhost/projeto_redes/camera.py");
          
          $output = shell_exec($path);
           }

         ?>
```

My python script works fine, and i also have this line of code in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Your path looks like a URL rather than a local file path. shell_exec won't know what to do with a URL

Comment: Even with this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\projeto_redes" dont work

Comment: Combine that with the advice below

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the shell_exec line exactly as if you were typing it into a command line normally. Meaning you need to include the python call and any arguments you need passed like:

`$path = escapeshellcmd("python localhost/projeto_redes/camera.py")`

Comment: Also I'm not sure 'where' the default path the shell that opens at points to, so it might be good practice to also include the full file path to your python file instead of a relative path.